# mysql insert from one table to another based on select

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Supposing we have

Table A

```
field 1 | field 2

orange  | fruit
apple   | fruit
```

and

Table B

```
field 1 | field 2

orange  | fruit
lemon   | fruit
```

And want to insert only the rows from Table B to Table A that don't match on field 1 so that Table A becomes:

Table A

```
field1  | field2

orange  | fruit
apple   | fruit
lemon   | fruit
```

Ive tried

```
insert into tableA (field1, field2)
select field1, field2 from tableB
where not exists 
(select * from tableA as a join tableB as b on a.field1 = b.field1)
```

(no insert)

and

```
insert into tableA (field1, field2)
select field1, field2  from tableA as a left join tableB as b on a.field1 = b.field1  
union 
select field1, field2  from tableA as s right join tableB as b on a.field1 = b.field1 
where a.field1 != b.field1
```

(incorrect insert)

Comment: Something like: `INSERT INTO tableA (field1, field2) SELECT b.field1, b.field2 FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN tableB b USING field1 WHERE a.field1 IS NULL` I think is what you're looking for. Start off by figuring out the SELECT that you want (all rows from tableB that are not in tableA), and then insert only those rows.

Comment: question uri trymysql:lab2017:basicops:uu579distantaystipulate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have your `NOT EXISTS` expression quite right, it needs to look at the value from `tableB` that you are trying to insert:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (field1, field2)
SELECT field1, field2 
FROM tableB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableA a WHERE a.field1 = b.field1)
```

Output of `SELECT * FROM tableA` after this query:

```
field1  field2
orange  fruit
apple   fruit
lemon   fruit
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gNR2LZ4ZtXS2eytmRM51rg/0)

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use union for that or use below code

```
INSERT INTO Table A SELECT * FROM Table B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE A Data
                  WHERE A.field1 = Data.field1 AND 
                  A.field2 = Data.field2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best solution, but this solution using joins worked for me:

```
INSERT INTO A(F1,F2)
SELECT * 
FROM A NATURAL RIGHT JOIN B AS TAB
WHERE TAB.F1 NOT IN (
SELECT F1
FROM A NATURAL JOIN B
);
```